# Set font and wrap-text in Squarify

Tags: python, matplotlib, squarify

In Matplotlib, I can plot a wrapped-text inside a box by

`ax.text(x_coord, y_coord, string, bbox = dict(boxstyle='round'), wrap = True, fontproperties = FontProperties_object)`

I can also set the font type through `matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties`.

Compared to `squarify`, it looks similar because there is text inside a square. How would I set the font and do text-wrapping with `squarify`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works.

`text_kwargs={"fontproperties": FontProperties_object}`. The text options are given as 'dict' as mentioned in

[https://github.com/laserson/squarify/blob/master/squarify/**init**.py](https://github.com/laserson/squarify/blob/master/squarify/__init__.py)

Comment: Still, the text doesn't wrap within the box